# Is it OK to programatically change the ID of Control in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, clientid

Is it wrong to programatically edit the id of a control in an ASPX file?

For example, if I have an aspx page with a  defined as such:

```
<div runat="server" ID="id1" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

will I get any problems if I in my code-behind file's page_load() do the following:

```
Control c = Page.FindControl("id1");
c.ID = "id2";
```

I do not get any errors doing this, I just want to know if I might bump into problems using the above code.

You might ask why I would want to change an id, and the answer is that I have a MasterPage that contains the above  element. Each content page that uses this masterpage, needs a distinct id for that div, because that id is used as a selector in my css file.

Another question is this: I have read that "Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property" from MSDN.
That is as I see it only a restriction when you specify the id in the aspx page, and not the programatically assigned id. Can anyone confirm?

Thanks a lot